# How to access to the returned elements from Laravel array validation?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

In laravel controller I receive the array of elements sent from `axios post` :

Here the code of this validation :

```
$request->validate([
        'segments.*.builder' => 'required',
        'segments.*.value' => 'required',
]);
```

in VueJs  :

```
                axios.post('/api/segment',
                    {
                        segments:newSegment,
                        name: newSegmentName,
                        rule:newSegmentRuleAndOr
                    }
                )
                    .then((response) => {
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        if (error.response.status === 422) {
                            console.log(error.response.data.errors);
                        }
                    });
```

the JS code above returns :

```
{__ob__: Observer}
segments.0.value: Array(1)
0: "The segments.0.value field is required."
length: 1
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
segments.1.value: (...)
segments.2.value: (...)
segments.3.value: (...)
```

My question is how to access to each values of this 422 response ? for example I want to use the Segment.1.value.

I tried :`console.log(error.response.data.errors[1])` but not working!

Answer (score 0):

In our project we use this lybary that help to deal with [with backend validation](https://github.com/spatie/form-backend-validation).

You make a post request like so:

```
    data() {
        return {
            visible: false,
            form: new Form({
                segments: null,
                name: "",
                rule: null
            })
        };
    },
```

Bind each field with form attribute

```
<input type="text"
   v-model="form.name"/>

// To display error
<span v-show="form.errors.has('name')"> {{ form.errors.first('name') }}  </span>
```

In the submit method:

```
try {
  // library under the hood will handle server validation errors. 
  // but you can do come custom staff in the catch section too. 
  await this.form.post("/api/segment");
  // success validation pass 
} catch (e) {
// TODO optinal Show notification "Validation error"
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it's not working! ` Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @MostafaAbdellaoui
Show me console.log(error.response.data.errors)

Comment: @MostafaAbdellaoui I have updated my answer take a look.